# Stop print-dialog when open page that contains Highcharts

Tags: javascript, printing, dialog, highcharts

When I open a page that contains Highcharts (I use 3 pie charts), the print dialog always shows and I don't know how it comes and to stop it.

This is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'users_contain',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Users'
            },
            // exporting: {
                // buttons: { 
                    // exportButton: {
                        // enabled:true
                    // },
                    // printButton: {
                        // enabled:false
                    // }

                // }
            // },
            exporting: {
                     enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,2) +' %';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,2) +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'User Usage',
                data: []
            }]
        } 
        $.getJSON("data/account_preview/user_usage.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });    

    });     

    </script>
```

I've tried to modify its exporting by add this

```
exporting: {
    enabled: false
}
```

or

```
exporting: {
      buttons: { 
                 exportButton: {
                      enabled:false
                 },
                 printButton: {
                      enabled:false
                 }
              }
          }
```

but, it also didn't work, it just make the button exporting be disabled in the chart.

Anyone know, how to stop print dialog when I open page that containt highcharts ?
Thank's.

Comment: Make sure you are not calling `chart.print()` anywhere in the code. Also, show more your code.

Comment: @PawełFus I've checked it, didn't exist. Okay.. Plz see the code is above :)

Comment: Okay, so your code looks properly.. What is displaying in print preview? Which one chart? You probably won't be able to recreate issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: @PawełFus Yaaaah I see.. It turns out has nothing to do with its highchart, because when I remove the chart and just write whatever character there, the print dialog still appears. But I have not found anywhere the print command in my folder, whether it's in its js or html files in it. Wonder why.. :/

Comment: Does this happen on other machines or only for you? Could you post link to your site?